# Sitecore 9 Installation error "Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Signer' during CreateSignedCert : NewSignedCertificate step

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I am trying to install Sitecore 9 in my Windows 10 box. At first attempt, it was failed with this [exception](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10117/sesecurityprivilege-error-during-sitecore-9-installation-on-windows-10)

After some modification, I re-executed Sitecore install script. This time, i came across new exception.

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Signer'. Cannot
>   convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type

[image]

When i first tried, this step was done but it failed second time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've created two certificates with precisely the same DNS name.

You can see in the verbose output that two certificates have been found as it lists two thumbprints.  These values are then returned as an array which causes the error as the `Signer` parameter only expects a single certificate.

I suggest removing one or both certificates and trying again. I'll add an issue to the SIF backlog to cater for this scenario.

Comment: I've added the issue to our backlog

Comment: How to Remove certificates. Please let me know the steps.

Comment: You can execute below PowerShell script to delete installed certificate..
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\<<id>> | Remove-Item

Comment: You can get more details here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/how-to-remove-all-certificates-installed-by-sitecore-9-sif-installation/10866#10866