# How to remove all certificates installed by Sitecore 9 SIF Installation?

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

Sometimes Sitecore 9 SIF installation script fails as multiple certificates found with same DNS name.

It may happened when you try to install Sitecore 9 using SIF and somehow it got failed due to any reason. You may tried to reinstall it. And If you tried to reinstall it with different user account, your SIF script might get failed with below exception.

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Signer'. Cannot
>   convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type

I found the solution [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10129/sitecore-9-installation-error-cannot-process-argument-transformation-on-paramet) and to continue with installation, I need to remove all already installed certificates but I don’t know, how to remove those from my system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you already know the thumbprint id (listed in the SIF console error), you can execute below PowerShell script to delete

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\<<thumbprint>> | Remove-Item
```

If you want to list of installed certificate for the location, you can execute below script to get that list.

```
Set-Location Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
Get-ChildItem | Format-Table Subject, FriendlyName, Thumbprint -AutoSize
```

Comment: It resolved my issue. Thanks Arvind for this post.

Comment: Hi @Jitendra, kindly vote up both question and answer. This would help other user to get confidence on it.

Comment: I'd also mention that the <<thumbprint>> is the <<firststring>> located in the xconnect-createcert.log file at 

Found Cert with thumbprint: <<firststring>> <<secondstring>>

Answer (score 1):

From [Habitat (feature/v9)](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/tree/feature/v9), they have powershell scripts to do this job

1. [Settings.ps1](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/feature/v9/settings.ps1)

[image]

2. [uninstall-xp0.ps1](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/feature/v9/uninstall-xp0.ps1)

[image]

3. The underline of Remove-SitecoreCertificate function at [Uninstall.psm1](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/feature/v9/build/Uninstall/Uninstall.psm1)

[image]

Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your "mmc" by writting "mmc" in your start and a popup will be shown click File>Add/remove snap-ins and then add certificates and from this folder you can remove the certifcate that were added by sitecore installation